# How can I combine two bit columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have two tables

1st table is named `Foo` and has a bit column `ACCESS_ALLOWED`

and another table called `Bar` and has the same bit column `ACCESS_ALLOWED`

So I want to write a SQL query that combines the results of a join between these tables and chooses the result based on what the individual values are. Sort of like `coalesce` function.

If both values are `1` then I want the query to return `1`, and if even one of the values is `0` then the query should return `0`. Is this possible?

Sample Data:

```
Foo Table

| ID | ACCESS_ALLOWED |
| 10 | 1              |
```

```
Bar Table

| ID | Foo_ID | ACCESS_ALLOWED |
| 5  | 10     | 0              |
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Comment: Your are describing expected behavior of  logical "***and***".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bitwise and operator `&`.

```
SELECT f.access_allowed & b.access_allowed access_allowed
       FROM foo f
            INNER JOIN bar b
                       ON b.foo_id = f.id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3053d7009e835a4cb3ffaf6406c1eb19)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select (case when f.access_allowed = 1 and b.access_allowed = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as both_together
from foo f join
     bar b
     on ? = ?   -- join keys here
```

Note that you need some way to `join` tables.  Or use `cross join` if each table only has one row.